# How to align a rectangle using kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Does anybody know the code to center align a rectangle using kivy but in a py file not kv. This is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.graphics import Color

class PongGame(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(255,255,255, mode='rgba')
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(self.x + 50, self.y + 50), size=(50, 50))
            # print(self.rect)

   


class PingyPong(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()
        
# class MakeRectangle(Widget):
#     def __init__(self, **kwargs):
#         with self.canvas:
#             # Color(255,255,255, mode='rgba')
#             self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(200, 200), size=(50, 50))

# class PingPong(App):
#     def build(self):
#         return Rectangle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PingyPong().run()
```

This is the output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lGDg.png)

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by getting Window size and then create rectangle at the center

```
from kivy.core.window import Window

class PongGame(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(255,255,255, mode='rgba')
            window_size = Window.size
            size = 50
            self.rect = Rectangle(pos=(window_size[0]/2-size/2, window_size[1]/2-size/2), size=(size, size))
            print()
```

Comment: i dont want to make a new rectangle by measuring the size of the screen. I simply want the code to align only one rectangle to the middle of the screen without the help of a new rectangle or the size of the screen.

Comment: Even making a new rectangle will work but i do not want that.

Comment: i got the answer now i dont need help. this case is dismissed. i had to set the pos_hint value of the rectangle as 0.5 as x and 0.5 as y. length of screen 1 middle is x=0.5, y=0.5